# Python list syncing each other while being copied

Tags: python-3.x, list, copy

I ran into this problem:

```
list01 = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]

list_copy = list01.copy()
list_copy[0][1] = "A"

print(list01)
print(list_copy)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 'A'], [3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 'A'], [3, 4, 5]]
```

So as you can see, when changing on element in the copied list, the no-copied-list also changes this element although the list_copy is created by .copy and not with: list_copy = list01 (in this case i understand why the lists are syncing each other)

Is there any solution or explanation for that, because I cant´t explain myself why this happens. I would like to do the change just to one of the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between copy and deepcopy

```
from copy import deepcopy
    
list01 = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
    
list_copy = deepcopy(list01)
list_copy[0][1] = "A"
print(list01)
print(list_copy)
```